# Declare variable in if statement and then using it later in code

Tags: c#, if-statement, declaration, statements

I am programming a console "game" and I need to declare a "hp" of character in IF statements which depends on level of this character.

```
if ((char_level > 0) && (char_level < 4))
        {
            char_hp = 100;
        }
if ((level > 4) && (level < 6))
        {
            char_hp = 120;
        }
if ((level > 6) && (level < 8))
        {
            char_hp = 150;
        }
if ((level > 8) && (level < 10))
        {
            char_hp = 180;
        }
```

Then I need to use it later in code in a fight. After a successful fight character gets a new level and after that, program will get back to check these IF statements and if level is bigger than 4, character's hp will be increased to 120. But declaration of char_hp in IF statements does not change the value of hp in general and when the next fight comes after reaching level 4, character's hp is still like at the end of previous battle was. I am new in C# programming and I have tried everything but I can't solve it, if it is possible.

The same problem is with the "hp" of enemy that is randomly generated...then I need to use it in that fight

```
if((level>0) && (level<4))
        {
            random_enemy_hp = RND.Next(89, 111);
            goto enemy;
        }
if((level>4) && (level<6))
        {
            random_enemy_hp = RND.Next(109, 141);
            goto enemy;
        }
if ((level > 6) && (level < 8))
        {
            random_enemy_hp = RND.Next(149, 184);
            goto enemy;
        }
if ((level > 8) && (level < 10))
        {
            random_enemy_hp = RND.Next(189, 221);
            goto enemy;
        }
```

EDIT: I meant "saving values to variables" in IF statements, so I can use them later in code. This is how my code starts, then there are "Console.WriteLine()"-s, principe of a fight and statements shown above.

```
string name;
int char_hp = 100;
int level = 1;
int random_enemy_hp;
Random RND = new Random();
```

Comment: `goto` in C#! It lives!

Comment: Whatever you want to do in C#, do not use "goto".

Comment: You're not _declaring_ `char_hp` in any of the code you've shown us.

Comment: instead of `=` use `+=`, if you want to increase the value

Comment: Show us where you declare char_hp

Comment: @arturgrzesiak that will not help. The post says the hp will increase TO the amount, bot BY the amount

Comment: An alternative could be to have helper method which return hp so that you can return the value instead of assigning value to a variable. (not sure what rest of your code is doing ... )

Comment: [goto](http://xkcd.com/292/)

Comment: I remember when i first started programming on the TI83 graphing calculator.  I used no functions or loops at all.  only goto

Comment: @SamIam the standard TI-83 program made in schools `:Lbl A :ClrHome :Output(4,2,"HELLO WORLD" :Goto A` <lots of blank lines to make it look like end of program> <Notes pertaining to topics on exam>` ;p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're completely on the wrong track. You should be doing something like:

```
int[] charLevelHp = { 100, 100, 100, 100,
                      120, 120, 120,
                      150, 150,
                      180, 180 };

int charLevel = 1;
int charHp = charLevelHp[charLevel];
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but notice that you're comparing with `char_level` for your first couple if-statement, but you're comparing to `level` for your subsequent if-statements

```
if ((char_level > 0) && (char_level < 4))
    {
        char_hp = 100;
    }
if ((level > 4) && (level < 6))
    {
        char_hp = 120;
    }
```

I think you might have intended to use `char_level` for all of the conditions.

```
if ((char_level > 0) && (char_level < 4))
    {
        char_hp = 100;
    }
if ((char_level > 4) && (char_level< 6))
    {
        char_hp = 120;
    }
```

If that's the issue, it would be consistent with the kinds of errors you're seeing.